# Как с помощью Ajax подтянуть значения в select?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Есть массив:

```
array (size=5)
  1821175 => 
    array
      'id' => int 1821175
      'name' => string 'Name'
      'statuses' => 
        array
          28235989 => 
            array
              'id' => int 28235989
              'name' => string 'status 1'
              'color' => string '#c1c1c1'
          28235992 => 
            array
              'id' => int 28235992
              'name' => string 'status 2'
              'color' => string '#c1c1c1'
   1931089 => 
    array
      'id' => int 1931089
      'name' => string 'Name 2'
      'statuses' => 
        array
          28235989 => 
            array
              'id' => int 28235989
              'name' => string 'status 3'
              'color' => string '#c1c1c1'
          28235992 => 
            array
              'id' => int 28235992
              'name' => string 'status 4'
              'color' => string '#99ccff'
```

Я получаю значения для каждого Name со своим ID таким образом:

```
<select class="form-control" id="Pipelineselect" name="Pipelineselect">
    <?php
    foreach ($PipeLines as $PipeLine) {
      echo "<option value=".$PipeLine['id'].">".$PipeLine['name']."</option>";
      }
    ?>
</select>
```

Дальше необходимо вывести ещё один `<select></select>`, в options  которого надо вставить соответствующие значения `$PipeLine['statuses']` для каждого из `$PipeLine`:
То есть, в итоге, результаты во второй селект бы подгружались ajax-ом 
это должно выглядеть как:

[image]

Помогите, как такое реализовать?

Comment: PHP код у вас в том же файле, что и html/js или отдельный?
Формирование массива происходит в какой момент? И в какой момент жизни приложения происходит построение списка из массива?
Пользователь это все инициирует своими действиями или в момент загрузки происходит?

Comment: Заранее ответы: 1.в том же. Кроме функции получения массива. 2.при загрузке страницы. 3. Первый селект при загрузке страницы. Второй должен бы погрузиться Аяксом... @Константин

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно и без `ajax`. Вы же берёте данные из этого же массива.

```php
<?php

$PipeLines = array(
    1821175 => array(
        'id' => '1821175',
        'name' => 'Name',
        'statuses' => array(
            28235989 => array('id' => '28235989',
                'name' => 'status 1',
                'color' => '#c1c1c1'),
            28235992 => array('id' => '28235992',
                'name' => 'status 2',
                'color' => '#c1c1c1')
        )
    ),
    1931089 => array(
        'id' => '1931089',
        'name' => 'Name 2',
        'statuses' => array(
            28235989 => array(
                'id' => '28235989',
                'name' => 'status 3',
                'color' => '#c1c1c1'),
            28235992 => array(
                'id' => 28235992,
                'name' => 'status 4',
                'color' => '#99ccff'
            )
        )
    )
);
print_r($PipeLines);

?>

<select class="form-control" id="Pipelineselect" name="Pipelineselect">
    <?php
    $Keys = array();
    echo "<option value=''></option>";
    foreach ($PipeLines as $ke=>$PipeLine) {
        echo "<option value=".$PipeLine['id'].">".$PipeLine['name']."</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
<?php
foreach ($PipeLines as $key=>$PipeLine) {
    echo '<select class="form-control" id="'.$key.'" name="'.$key.'" hidden>';
    foreach ($PipeLine['statuses'] as $status)
    echo "<option value=".$status['id'].">".$status['name']."</option>";
    echo '</select>';
}
?>

<script language="JavaScript">
    let z = JSON.parse('<?php print_r(json_encode($PipeLines))?>');
    Object.keys(z).forEach(function (key){
        var Press = z[key]['id'];

        document.getElementById("Pipelineselect").addEventListener("change", function() {
            var e = document.getElementById("Pipelineselect");
            var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            if (strUser == Press) {
                document.getElementById(Press).hidden = false;
            }else {
                document.getElementById(Press).hidden = true;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Огонь! То что надо!

Comment: Есть одно но. Если задать уникальный name, то при таком раскладе в $_POST будет отправляться всегда последний hidden select, а не выбранный. А если не задавать, то в POST попадает массив из всех возможных select=>option , а не только выбранных.

Comment: @theblackpost Где задавать уникальный name? Все параметры и в селектах и в php зависят исключительно от `id`. `Name` только выводится в селект текстом.

Comment: Не спорю, но как-то надо передать в POST конкретное значение выбранного option.. Иначе какой смысл от формы))) Сейчас-то передается всё подряд. и не разобрать какой из них выбран: https://prnt.sc/r09eff

Comment: @theblackpost А в чём сложность? ))) Отслеживаете выбранное поле через js, получаете его значение и отправляете в `POST`, да можно даже и через PHP обернув всё в форму ) Но это уже другой вопрос, нежели в самом вопросе.

Comment: @theblackpost Понятно, убрали решение как верное. Вы оформили вопрос. Вам был дан конкретный ответ, который полностью соответствует Вашему вопросу. И Вы решили убрать это решение как верное. Если у Вас появляются другие вопросы - их необходимо оформлять отдельно. Кто же Вам будет помогать после такого?

Comment: Прошу прощения. Тут ребенок балуется у компьютера, нравятся ему цветные галочки.... Не специально убрал решение.

В PHP-то как раз всё и обернуто в форму. Но как я уже написал выше передается массив со всеми возможными вариантами select option. Не понимаю как вытащить непосредственно выбранный option.. (

Comment: @theblackpost Либо необходимо обернуть селекторы в форму `<form action="ФайлВкоторыйБудутПередаватьсяДанные.php" method="post">`, кнопка `<button formmethod="post">Тык</button>` и в конце `</form>` Тогда после выборов селектов и нажатии на кнопку - данные будут передаваться в файл, в котором их можно получить и с ними работать. Или, если без нажатия кнопки, то отслеживать изменение через `js` при помощи `onchange` И так же эти данные можно обрабатывать и отправлять куда угодно.

Comment: Вы не поняли. Форма уже есть: <form method="POST"> </form> обработка в этом же файле if(isset($_POST['add'])){ ... }.
Но данные приходят вот такие: prnt.sc/r09eff  . Все все все selectы. Ведь они же просто hidden, значения то в них есть: https://prnt.sc/r0a87v

Comment: То есть по сути здест только второй вариант, через js.. Но вот тут не пойму как верный обернуть...

Comment: @theblackpost Вы проверяете нажатие элемента с именем `add`, чтобы отслеживать первый селект используйте `if(isset($_POST['Pipelineselect']){$param = $_POST['Pipelineselect']}` Другие селекты (выбранные), можно отслеживать через этот же самый массив через цикл. `foreach ($PipeLines as $key=>$PipeLine) { if(isset($_POST['$key]){$param1 = $_POST['$key]}` Могу так же пример и на `js` написать с получением выбранных значений.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104268/discussion-between-theblackpost-and-denis640kb).

Comment: Я, кажется понял в чем была проблема.

Comment: @theblackpost Это хорошо ) Всё получилось у Вас?

Answer (score 2):

Делаете `ajax` запрос на сервер и с сервера возвращаете готовый json объект. Затем в `success` вы ищете ваш `select` чтото типо `$('#select-id')` проходите циклом по полученному `json` и создаете `option` елементы для вашего селекта. Думаю что понятно изложил, в случае чего задавайте вопросы